# Array Value Gets Reinitialize when form is submitted using php

Tags: php, html, css

I want to Create an ItemList and simply display it. For this, I have created an array and a form with add item "text field" and "submit" button.

The problem is when I add a new value by clicking on the "submit" button, the page gets reloaded and previously added values are lost. I want previously added values to persist, without storing these data into the database.

Please help me I am a beginner in this field.

Code :

```
<?php
  session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>PHP ItemList</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <?php
          $itemList = array();
          if ( $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
                array_push( $itemList, $_POST["Item"] );
                print_r( $itemList );
          }
      ?>
       <h3>Add : </h3>
       <form  method="POST" action = "index.php">
         <p>Item : <input type="text" name="Item"></p>
         <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
       </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're looking for [sessions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, Can you please explain what am I missing? @El_Vanja

Comment: Requests are isolated. The next submit knows nothing about the data from the previous one. In order to make your application remember the state, you have to save that data somewhere. Since you've mentioned you don't want a database, the next options are either files or sessions. And I feel a session might fit your needs better than a file.

Comment: Thank you very much, I would look into it, your help means a lot to me @El_Vanja

Comment: I have edited the code Link - https://pastebin.pl/view/c7331334 , But Still I have the same problem @El_Vanja ,

Comment: Because you always initialize the session as an empty array: `$_SESSION[ 'itemList' ] = array();`.

Comment: Issue got resolved, Thank you very much @El_Vanja